# Background image in Navigation Bar Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to add an image background to a navigation bar in Swift 3? Where should I do it? Can I do it in the App Delegate?

I tried many of the solutions I found online but none worked for me.

Thanks!

Comment: let image = UIImage(named: "navBarImage.png")
        UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(image, for: .default)

Answer (score 4):

Try this one at AppDelegate at didFinishLaunchingWithOptions.

```
//Image Background Navigation Bar
let navBackgroundImage:UIImage! = UIImage(named: "backgroundNB.png")
UINavigationBar.appearance().setBackgroundImage(navBackgroundImage, for: .default)
```

Answer (score -1):

To achieve this, you can follow below steps.

1. Make an outlet of the navigation bar in your view controller.

   ```
   @IBOutlet var navBar: UINavigationBar!
   ```
2. Now, In viewDidLoad() function, write the following code to set background and shadow image as per the need.

   ```
   navBar.delegate = self
   navBar.setBackgroundImage(UIImage.init(named: "BackgroundImage"), for: .any, barMetrics: .default)
   navBar.shadowImage = UIImage.init(named: "ShadowImage")
   ```

It is working perfact with swift 3.. Happy Coding..!!

Comment: Thanks Nirmit, how to have this work everywhere in the app? My navigation bar is in a Navigation Controller, not in a View Controller.

Comment: @Tasneem , if you want to set navigation bar color at every view controller, you have to do it at AppDelegate. But, If you want to set customizable at every view controller, the answer Nirmit provided is completely useful

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @Tasneem Make a generalized method in some class and use it or the second approach is set navigation bar appearance in app delegate.